# How large of a 3D feature map can be hosted for Google Cloud Anchors?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I am using [Google Cloud Anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/cloud-anchors/overview-unity) to create AR experiences. Cloud Anchors create a 3D feature map of the area around the anchor point and uploads it to the cloud so that other people can resolve the anchor.

I would like to know if there is any **limit on how big this 3D feature map could be** (in terms of **area**; meters preferably). If it helps to make the question less broad, the area will have a good number of distinct feature points but could be big, like a neighborhood.

My search on Google yielded no satisfactory results. The only limitations I could find about data storage limitations (for Google Cloud Anchors) are these -

[image]

Also, in case it is required, I am building an Android AR app using ARCore 1.18 and Unity 2019.4.5f1 (LTS).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific limitation to the area you can use, but naturally, the larger the area the more room there is for errors. I've never tried to do it on a neighborhood scale. For reference, but I managed to get good results for a big square but not great results for Washington Square Park in NYC.

Comment: Ohk. Looks like there's no limitation yet. That's really good. I was wondering how Google is able to prevent people from exploiting this point. But then the anchors are only hosted for 24 hours!